# how to configure a SMTP server in windowx xp to send mails to gmail?

Tags: smtp, email, redmine, outgoing-mail

forgive my ignorance, I thought it was going to be a no-brainer but I still couldn't figure it out

I'm using redmine (is a ticket system made with rails) and it has the option of sending you mails to notify events.

So far now I could not configure a smtp server to relay mails to my gmail account.

I want to configure some local client (thunderbird, for example) and to be able to send mails to xx@gmail.com using my own smtp server, and then I'll configure redmine to do the same.

I've followed this tutorial:

http://www.ehow.com/how_4489548_set-up-smtp-server-windows.html

and configured thunderbird with localhost as outgoing mail...

I get the following:

in F:\Inetpub\mailroot\Badmail\0029d2423191605200900000001.BAD

Final-Recipient: rfc822;xxxx@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550-5.7.1 [201.250.95.2] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your
550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at http://mail.google
550 5.7.1 .com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10336 6si8453947yxg.40

well at http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=10336

'The IP you're using to send email is not authorized...'
In order to prevent spam, Gmail refuses mail when the sending IP address does not match the sending domain. To send mail from your server to Gmail, we suggest using the SMTP relay provided by your ISP. Please note that we are unable to whitelist IP addresses or otherwise make exceptions at this time.

any idea how to do it???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's error explanation is pretty straightforward. If you want to deliver to them, they check to make sure you're not using a bogus sender domain.

How about you just use gmail's own SMTP server for relaying? You get the advantage of not having to worry about who you can subsequently deliver to (since you're authenticating to their SMTP, they'll happily deliver anywhere).

[This](http://blog.expandrive.com/2008/12/04/redminerails-email-through-gmail-smtp/) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you're sending mail from "me@example.com", but "example.com" doesn't specify your IP address as an allowed sender for that domain -- by default only the *destination* server for the domain (the MX) is allowed to send mail coming *from* the domain.

If Google is your mail provider, you should be relaying the mail through them, use smtp.gmail.com (which requires you to log in, by the way).

Otherwise, you should be relaying the mail through whoever is your mail provider. If **you** are your mail provider, then your DNS settings are probably incorrect. In that case, I would suggest hiring a tech professional to examine your setup and give you suggestions on what to do next.